# How to use saveAll with associated datas?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I have a attributes_products and a products table, i don't know why but my data are saved twice (for the attributes_products_table). so if i go to the product page i will insert one row, i will get one data but if there is one data for example, cake will save this data twice plus the new one. Thanks

```
    if($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put') ){

                $d = $this->request->data;

                if($this->Product->saveall($d, array('deep' => 'true'))){

                    $this->Session->setFlash("Le produit a bien été enregistré","notif");

                }
}
```

Product Model ;

```
  public $hasMany = array(
    'AttributsProduct' => array(
      'className' => 'AttributsProduct',
      'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
      'dependent' => false
    ),
    'ImagesProduct' => array(
      'className' => 'ImagesProduct',
      'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
      'dependent' => false
    )
  );
Array
(
    [Product] => Array
        (
            [company_id] => 18
            [name] => iWatch
            [category_id] => 1
            [description] => iWatch
            [id] => 4
            [main_image_file] => Array
                (
                    [name] => 
                    [type] => 
                    [tmp_name] => 
                    [error] => 4
                    [size] => 0
                )

        )

    [AttributsProduct] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [attribut_id] => 2
                    [description] => sceen
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [attribut_id] => 1
                    [description] => monitor
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: i just fixed it, the solution is to put the id inside the loop of the attributes, <input name="data[AttributsProduct][<?php echo $v['AttributsProduct']['id']; ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $v['AttributsProduct']['id']; ?>" type="hidden">

Answer (score 0):

The new generated array for the HABTM record needs to know the existent id if it already exists, or a null if it's supposed to create a new record. In any case, it should have the belongsTo id as well for both tables in the relationship.